# command-line or terminal?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags:

[command-line](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) and [terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal)

Neither have tag wikis and frankly I don't know which of them to use. Is there a difference?

Comment: In your case, command line.

Comment: How do you differentiate between their uses?

Comment: Command line is about running commands. Terminal is about the application itself.

Comment: So only questions specific to the default terminal emulator should be tagged with [tag:terminal]?

Comment: Anything about it, yes. e.g. settings, colours etc

Comment: Got it. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal) is for the actual GUI program, `pantheon-terminal`. Use this tag when configuring it, like changing the transparency, text colour or font etc.

---

Command line is for running commands - this could be using any terminal - `tty`, `gnome-terminal` or `pantheon-terminal`. Whichever it is, *if this tag is used, the terminal being used shouldn't matter*. Anything tagged [command-line](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) should apply to any bash terminal.

Comment: I will suggest the tag wikis later today.

Comment: [tag:terminal] should redirect to [tag:pantheon-terminal], for clarity. This was previously discussed here (more comments are welcome): http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/24

Comment: @waldyrious I've commented there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference between “[command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)” and “terminal”. The most relevant difference, in fact, is between [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)#Text_.28CLI.29_shells) and [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal). The shell is the program that interprets commands. It's also the program that displays a prompt and provides facilities to edit commands when you type it. [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) is the default shell; there are others. The terminal (more precisely a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator)) is the program that provides basic character input/output. [Pantheon Terminal](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-terminal) is the default terminal emulator programs; there are others.

What does this mean in terms of tags? Given that the command line is not the primary focus of this site, I think it would make sense to have a tag [command-line](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) that covers all command line issues, whether they're with bash or with the terminal (most issues are with the shell anyway).

There shouldn't be a tag [terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal), but there should be a tag [pantheon-terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-terminal) for issues about Pantheon Terminal specific features such as using tabs, saving sessions, configuring colors, etc.

There shouldn't be a tag [shell](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell), but there should be a tag [bash](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) for bash-specific issues such as prompt settings, command history, command line editing, etc. There should also be a tag [shell-script](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) for when the shell is used to run scripts rather than interactively.

I expect questions to be asked mostly with the [command-line](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) tag, and tags such as [bash](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [pantheon-terminal](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-terminal) to be added where relevant.

This isn't the tags we use on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) — there we strictly distinguish between generic shell use ([shell]), features of specific shells ([bash], etc.), terminal issues ([terminal]), features of specific terminal emulators ([xterm], etc.), and we have a tag [command-line] that we don't quite know what to do with. But U&L has a very different audience — primarily command-line-based — so different tags are warranted.